# Switch Case <audio>

Tags: php, audio, switch-statement

I'm trying to use audio in a switch case thingy, I'm pretty new and I don't really know how If it's possible

This is what I have:

```
    //Chooses a random number 
    $num = Rand (1,2); 
    //Based on the random number, gives a quote 
    switch ($num)
        {
        case 1:
        echo    <audio controls autoplay>
                <source src="a.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
                </audio> ;
        break;
        case 2:
        echo "Test";
        break;
        }
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the quotes for your `echo` statement, and Rand needs to be lowercase without a space after it.

Try this:

```
//Chooses a random number 
$num = rand(1,2); 
//Based on the random number, gives a quote 
switch ($num)
    {
    case 1:
    echo    '<audio controls autoplay>
            <source src="a.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
            </audio>';
    break;
    case 2:
    echo "Test";
    break;
    }
```

You can use single quotes or double quotes for your echo statement, but in this case I'd recommend single quotes for two reasons:

1. You already have double quotes in your text (inside the HTML tags) and they would break the double quotes since they would be considered the end of the text, but shouldn't be.
2. Single quotes work better for multiple lines of text in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Add single quotes for your first "echo" printing